# Problem in booting Windows Vista after repairing using a boot repair disk

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader, windows-vista

Been using Vista and I recently installed Ubuntu 11 in a separate hard disk(in BIOS, this hard disk was set for the 'Boot from' option)..Apart from the partitions used for Ubuntu, there are 2 more partitions(NTFS) in that hard disk..Then I installed Windows 7 on one of those partitions (just to see which Windows operating system I'd like to keep on  using, along with Ubuntu)..But after installing Windows 7, the OS selection menu didn't appear anymore and had to fix it using the Boot-Repair-Disk... It kinda worked.. Now the OS selection menu is displayed.. But whenever I **select Vista**, it boots Windows 7...any thoughts on how to fix this?

here's the link to the log generated by boot repair >> http://paste.debian.net/202691 I'm new to Ubuntu btw..

Comment: you could try opening terminal and type:
sudo update-grub
It should detect all the installs and set them right

Comment: pubuduwo, uba okkoma partitions anaa gena... ow ow, grub update karala balapan, but vista nati vei.. Just 7n ubuntu

Comment: `sudo update-grub` won't help as it was already used by Boot-Repair without success.

Answer (score 0):

1. **WORKAROUND**: You can boot directly Vista by making your BIOS boot on Vista disk  (82GB). But then you need to make your BIOS boot on the Ubuntu disk to get access to GRUB menu (Ubuntu+Win7).
2. **FIX ATTEMPT:** the bug may be due to the old GRUB version (1.99-12) contained in 11.10. You can use the last version of GRUB (2.00) by running `Boot-Repair --> Advanced options --> GRUB Options tab --> tick "Upgrade GRUB to its most recent version" --> Apply`. If that doesn't fix the problem, i recommend you create a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+filebug), and indicate the link of the report in comment so that we can follow-up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.The first one is what I've been using after the mess up. In the second solution, did you mean to say 'recent version'? It said "Upgrade GRUB to its last version".Anyhow, I didn't dare use it, incase it messed things up more.Instead I selected the recommended repair option again.This time, GRUB seems to have been placed in the disk with Vista as well(grub menu appeared) and Vista was booted, when selected.The old problem(when booting from the other disk) is still there though,it still loads 7, instead of Vista. Included what I did, incase it helps someone else

Comment: yes, the exact label is `Upgrade GRUB to its most recent version`. I will fix my previous message.